# Editor and Dropdown for Same Attribute in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add Editor and Dropdown list for a single field. Such case arises if one agency is not already in the database, the user enters the agency name else the value will be selected from dropdown. Please suggest me suitable answers. Here only the first Editor or Dropdownlist for is selected else the second is null, I want to pass the text value in case dropdown is not selected and pass the dropdown value leaving the textbox empty.

```
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgentName)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AgentName, ViewBag.Agency as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select")
```

Comment: You cannot bind 2 form controls to the same property (the `DefaultModelBinder` only binds the first. Create a view model with separate properties

Comment: Seems that the posted value is `EditorFor` instead of `DropDownListFor`. As per model binding the first helper will be posted, other helpers with same viewmodel properties are ignored. Use separate properties for both helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead you can take two properties...
as

```
public string SelectedAgent{ get; set; }
public string AgentName { get; set; }
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedAgent, ViewBag.Agency as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgentName)
```

and while inserting check which property has a value....

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.AgentName) ? model.SelectedAgent : model.AgentName
```

Answer (score 0):

With addition of one more field in Class, I added a few line code in controller and View, and finally got the answer.

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AgentName, ViewBag.Agency as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AgentNameNew)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgentName)
```

**Controller:**

```
internationalarrival.AgentName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(internationalarrival.AgentNameNew) ? internationalarrival.AgentName : internationalarrival.AgentNameNew;
db.InternationalArrivals.Add(internationalarrival);
db.SaveChanges();
```

and In

**Model:**

```
public partial class InternationalArrival
{
    public decimal InternationalArrivalId { get; set; }
    public string AgentName { get; set; }

    public string AgentNameNew { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string AgentCode { get; set; }


    public Nullable<DateTime> ArrivalDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Nullable<int> ForPAX { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Nullable<int> IndPAX { get; set; }
}
```